# Is there a way to modify a Microsoft Word footer using Apache POI?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I need to modify the content of a Word footer using a Java API.

The [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) project [does not](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html) [seem to](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/quick-guide.html) support this functionality:

> WARNING - you shouldn't change the headers or footers, as offsets are not yet updated!

My question is twofold:

1. Does anyone know of a way to do this using POI's API?
2. Is there a different java API which does offer this functionality?

Comment: What file type do you want to make the change in .doc or .docx?

Comment: Really both, though either one would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Can't speak for POI but [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/aspose.words-for-.net-and-java/default.aspx) will let you manipulate Doc files. It ain't cheap though.